# Django URLs from different apps in just the base one

Tags: python, django

So I have 2 apps for my django project. In the default mysite folder, you have the `urls.py` file. I cant seem to find out how to write all my urls for all the apps in just the one urls.py file.

I have tried this:

`from reviews.models import *`

however that isnt working.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Just realised that i was importing the models instead of the views.

the code above should be `from reviews.views import *`

Comment: I would import the views themselves by name, rather than using `*`.  Your current version is a major code smell and violates best practices

Comment: Right ok. Should I do the same when I import my models into my views? Also why is it considered a major code smell?

Comment: correct, I would make it a habit to import by specific name, and avoid `*` unless you're absolutely certain that you need everything in the module being imported.  For more reading, check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad

Answer (score 0):

Try and prevent confusion with explicit view names, *explicit is better than implicit*

```
from reviews import views as reviews_views
from other_app import views as other_app_views
```